# Using rydurham Sentinel on specific route in Laravel 5.1

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

I am using sentinel by Ryan Durham https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel with Laravel 5.1.

I used to use Confide https://github.com/Zizaco/confide with Larvel 4.2.

With Confide I was able to add an auth to any route like this

```
// Applies auth filter to the routes within orders/ 
Route::when('orders/*', 'auth');
```

I've searched through Sentinel documentation for this feature but I cannot find out how to get this done. I can put an auth for say `admin` or `user` in the construct of a controller, but I need to have specific auth abilities on specific routes.

My question is, how can I redirect a `user` who goes to a route only for `admin` using rydurham sentinel in a clean fashion the same as Confide?

Answer (score 0):

You should use sentinel middlewares on routes. Something like

```
Route::get('orders', ['middleware' => 'sentry.admin', function () {
    // return view;
}]);
```